# How to handle escaping a get-credential request in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Say we have `get-credential` in PS and the user hits escape during the credential prompt - in my case the script continues (but will fail down the road).  How do you capture that escape and act on it (e.g. `write-host; exit` etc...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via the `-ErrorAction` parameter you can define what the cmdlet should do in case of an error. In case of `stop` the cmdlet throws an exception that you can catch.

```
 Try {
     Get-Credential -ErrorAction Stop 
 }catch { 
     Write-Error "User canceled. Exception $($_.Exception)"
     return 
 }
```

If you don't want to catch exceptions, you can use Powershells automatic `$error`-variable:

```
  # User cancels the dialog
  $error.Clear()
  Get-Credential
  if ($error.Count -gt 0) {
     Write-Error "User canceled"
  }
```

Since `$error` will include errors of beforehand called cmdlets, you've to clear the content. You also have the option to define your own error-variable via the `-ErrorVariable` parameter.

Below links contain more information about this topic:

- [devblog msdn](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/)
- [about_commonparameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6)